# VBA Connection not available on Windows 8

Tags: vba, vb6, connection, vb6-migration, autocad

I am portingcode to Autocad 2014 on a Windows 8 Machine from Autocad 2000i on a Windows XP machine. (A big jump, I know).

When I attempt to run a vba command, It takes me to the VBA debugger and highlights this line and gives this error:

[image]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: did you set all necessary references? possibly you need to set it again to new ADO library .

Comment: Not sure what that means. I am sure your suggestion is right, but I am a total noob and am gonna need a few more details :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADO is not available on 64-bit machines. Your VBA code will not work and you will have to port this to VB.NET. See this video from Autodesk for more help coming up with a workaround.

http://download.autodesk.com/media/adn/DevTV_VBA_Migration/english/DevTV_VBA_To_VBdotNet_Migration_English.html